# MavenSession not populated

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I'm trying to create my first Maven plugin, and for that I need to access MavenSession in my Mojos. I found in many places that the following snippet should be enough, but I always end up with the mavenSession object as null, although in the Maven log (of the POM.xml using my plugin) it seems like the maven session is passed, or at least populated - but is not injected into the MavenSession object.

Can anyone please tell me what I am missing?

Thanks!

---

```
/**
 * The Maven Session
 *
 * @required
 * @readonly
 * @parameter
 * expression="${session}"
 */
private MavenSession mavenSession;
```

I also added the following to the POM.xml of the plugin (based on a comment I found somewhere):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

**And this from the log:**

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'com.ofernicus.helpers:resource-helper:1.0-SNAPSHOT:iterate' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@1a785a79
[DEBUG]   (f) mavenProject = MavenProject: com.ofernicus.consumers:resource-helper-consumer:1.0-SNAPSHOT @ C:\Users\oferlan\workspaces\Maven\PluginConsumer\resource-helper-consumer\pom.xml
```

Comment: Are you talking about (unit-)test time or about runtime?

Comment: @RobertScholte - I guess you'd call it runtime - I'm trying to call this plugin from a different/separate Maven project.

Comment: Where is it `null`? Right at the start of your `execute` method?

Comment: And what about other properties? Are they injected fine?

Comment: Can you please show your full pom?

Comment: @mystarrocks - thanks, your question is what eventually led me to the answer, which is that those members are populated only inside the execute() method - and not in other methods in the class (even though they are class members).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the responses here, I eventually found the issue:

I was trying to access the mavenSession and mavenProject from a method that was **called** from the execute() method. I assumed that once injected, these members are accessible and populated everywhere in the scope of my Mojo - which is wrong. I moved my code into the execute() method itself and the issue was resolved.

Thanks, everyone!

Comment: I made the exact same mistake. Thanks everybody :)

Answer (score 1):

Missed Parameter annotation:

```
@Parameter(defaultValue = "${session}")
private MavenSession session;
```

Comment: Thanks, Hersh - I tried your suggestion but I'm still getting (MavenSession) session as null.

Comment: @Hersh, no, the OP did not miss the parameter annotation, he/she has used a [javadoc tag](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-java/index.html) instead, which although is not recommended will still work.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have references to two fields: In your code you call this field `mavenSession`, but when looking at the output of Maven it refers to `session`. It looks like you're questioning one which isn't properly injected with a `MavenSession`.

Comment: I actually had both session and mavenSession defined, once injected via @Parameter and one via JavaDoc tag - but both were null. Anyway - issue is resolved now (as I added in my own answer).

Answer (score 0):

Maven uses `plexus` under the hood to inject the components/elements from the maven project/`pom.xml` into a plugin project, so you must make sure you include the relevant dependencies.

Here's a complete list of dependencies you can include to your `pom.xml` to bring all the necessary dependencies transitively into your project.

And prefer [mojo annotations](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/index.html) to [mojo javadoc tags](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-java/). You can get a complete picture of the plugin tools involved reading [this](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/index.html).

```
<properties>
  <pluginTools.version>3.3</pluginTools.version> <!-- be sure to use the latest version in here -->
</properties>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-plugin-tools-api</artifactId>
  <version>${pluginTools.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>${pluginTools.version}</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The expression: `Maven uses pluxus` is not true anymore since Maven 3.0 it used guice under the hood. But it has compatibility layer (sisu) to support older plugins (See https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-4749).